# compute url rating in the particular time period

Tags: sql, hive

I am new with hive and SQL. And I have some difficulties with writing of query on hive. The fact is that I need to calculate the ranking of visits to urls on weekend between 08:00 and 17:59 (it is working hours) and between 18:00 and 07:59 (it is free hours). I have data base , which stores userId, timestamp (when user attended the url). And I need to select url, and this two ranking of visits for work hours and free hours on weekend. I don't understand how to do that. I suppose I have to use WHERE to filter data with timestamps which were on weekend. But I don't understand how to compute two ranking of visits.

```
Example of the row in db:

1234543 1419638963 site.com
where 
userId = 1234543
unix timestamp = 1419638963
url = site.com
```

I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.

Comment: I add an example of a row in a table in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below SQL.
I am a little confused on `rank` of columns. Because rank can be based on many things. i simply order the data based on count of visit. see if it suits your requirement.
I used `from_unixtime(ux_time)` to calculate the date and time from your data. `overall_rank` should give you overall rank based on both counts.

```
select 
url,
cnt_working,
cnt_free,
row_number() over (order by cnt_working,cnt_free) overall_rank
from 
(
select 
sum(case when hour(from_unixtime(ux_time)) >=8 and hour(from_unixtime(ux_time)) < 18 then 1 else 0 end ) cnt_working,
sum(case when hour(from_unixtime(ux_time)) >=8 and hour(from_unixtime(ux_time)) < 18 then 0 else 1 end ) cnt_free,
url
from mytable
where extract(dayofweek FROM (from_unixtime(1419638963) ))  IN (1,7) -- to include only sat,sun
group by visit
) rs 
order by 2,3
```